# Unable to get Receiver List in Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I am doing a sender and receiver app for our site using Chrome API, currently when user wants to connect chromecast, its opening extension with device list, but in youtube its showing right there..

i am unable to get receiver list when i initiate chromecast sender app, all i am getting is device available or not, there are some old examples which uses cast.Api.addReceiverListener() to get the list of available devices.. but currently its not working and there seems to be no other option to do it..

i can see youtube and netflix are doing it though

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not officially supported in the current Chrome API. YouTube is likely using undocumented features or other DIAL functionality.

This might be of interest: https://github.com/jloutsenhizer/CR-Cast/wiki/Chromecast-Implementation-Documentation-WIP

Comment: Hi, i can see what are you saying..but youtube or netflix are able to inject api_script.js which as cast api settings into their html, but for me its only loading api_iframe_script.js.. i have whitelisted all IP, APP and Device

Comment: That's because they are on the V1 API. All of our apps in the V2 api. They're are phasing out the V1 api and it won't be much longer until it's gone. V2 API's must use the Cast Extension.

Comment: @MatBee yes that shld be the problem.. i thank both of you for taking time to respond.. similar issue can be found in the google cast official community https://plus.google.com/101736626284909696727/posts/i3twPMZmyLF