# how to show available chrome cast devices when cast icon is clicked?

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I need help on showing list of available chrome cast devices when chrome cast icon is clicked. Just like what youtube does. See image below.

[image]

As of now, when I click the cast icon on my HTML5 app, the devices selection pop-ups on Chrome cast extension, see image below.

[image]

I want my app to show the cast devices selection like youtube does. Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation at https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: @AliNaddaf, yes I've read the docs. On what part do you want me to read?... @ CommonsWare, I haven't encountered any problem but I just want my HTML app to work like what youtube does where is pop-ups a div when cast icon is clicked. See image above.

Comment: @NinoPaolo Documentations explain how to set up cast icon on all three platforms and we have a bunch of samples for that too so I don't understand why you are asking this question when there is plenty of material and samples doing it already.

Comment: Hi @AliNaddaf "how to set up cast icon". The question is about the pictured in-page Chromecast selection menu, not Chromecast icons. The same menu is used by Netflix and YouTube, so it seems to be a built-in component. And it's not in scope for a website to generate as it doesn't know the available Chromecasts. The docs at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender don't seem to explain how this menu is generated. Could you please identify where in the docs this menu is explained.

Comment: As I said a couple of times already, read the docs. Here is where you can find the tutorial on chrome sender: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender If that is not enough, grab one of the sample projects that is for iOS sender, try it and learn how things can be done. Beyond that, I am not able to help you unless you start doing your part.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Can you please be at least more specific. I'm sorry to say this but referring to that chrome_sender doc page is not very helpful. That's where we start reading before we start developing. Just FYI, I've downloaded and tested sample apps on googlecast github page. Unfortunately, I didn't find any answer. I wouldn't be asking this if I knew the answer. That will be stupid. ou could probably be helpful if you point a function or something on this page ( https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/index-all ). That would be a lot more clearer.

Comment: You could find related questions here ( https://plus.google.com/101736626284909696727/posts/i3twPMZmyLF ) and here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663677/unable-to-get-receiver-list-in-chromecast ). Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did the samples that you download work for you or not? If not, then you are setting things up incorrectly. If they worked, look at a simple one and experiment with it and see how it is doing things. If the documentation in tutorial + samples are not enough for you to even get started, then I won't be able to provide more guidance until you start working and writing code and ask more specific question; this forum is for those who do some work, try tings out and run into issue; they show their work and what they have done and explain the particular issue they are running into.

Comment: Hi @AliNaddaf, I made a simple example ( http://jsfiddle.net/paolooo/Kv9Tw/ ) to play cast icon. When you click the cast icon in the "Result" window pane. It will pop-up the list of devices. See screenshot ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/Px3hv.png ). Which is good! But what we want is to pop-up a div with the list of devices above the cast icon, just like youtube. See screenshot ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/8SMlf.png ). Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sample protocol for  'scan' and for 'device' discovery is in this node [project](https://github.com/vincentbernat/nodecastor)

in these classes:

lib/device.js

lib/scanner.js

some sample output:

```
rob@ nodecastor$ bin/chromecast discover

info: + borneoTV (192.168.1.141:8009) [8235f790a1597865d6d2be26728282dc]
```

Since You use JS, maybe the node stuff helps you??

Answer (score 0):

According to chromecast documentation:
[image: Printscreen of documentation]

I only can get receiver name after selected the device in chromecast popup, so this function is executed: function onRequestSessionSuccess(e){...}

So, I explored object returned, precisely in attribute: e.receiver.friendlyName

I hope have helped you :)